# Very slow LINQ query using EF and Oracle Table

Tags: sql, .net, oracle, linq, entity-framework

I have an MVC3 application using EF4, hitting an Oracle backend.  I've run into a strange problem accessing one of the tables with link.  The table is called EXPENSES, and it has a identity column (type: NUMBER) called PK.  Despite its name, the PK column is not actually a Primary Key--it just has a unique index on it.

When I do a LINQ query against this table, it is extremely slow, even bringing back < 100 records.  Here is the query:

```
List results = dataContext.EXPENSE.Where(x => x.PROJECT_ID == trgProjectID).ToList();
```

I've looked at the raw SQL it is sending to the database (using ToTraceString) and the SQL itself runs very quickly (less than 2 seconds).

Note that my query does not include the PK column itself.  However, the PROJECT_ID column also has an index on it (a non-unique index, in this case).

Strangely, if I "hack" the query so that I also filter on PK in my Where statement (basically, I hard-coded the PK values into it, just to see what would happen), the query completes very quickly.

I am guessing this problem has something to do with Key resolution inside the EF layer.  I tried changing the MergeOption on the Expenses DBSet to "NoTracking" but this has no effect.

Any ideas would be much appreciated...!

Comment: Does project id and trgProject ID are the same type?
Maybe you can do the exercise of both query and take a look at the execution plan, this can give you more information about whats is happening in sql server

Answer (score 2):

[.AsNoTracking()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method may help to improve the performance of the query - this means that Entity Framework won't try to keep track of any changes to the entities.

```
List results = dataContext.EXPENSE
                          .AsNoTracking()
                          .Where(x => x.PROJECT_ID == trgProjectID)
                          .ToList();
```

This code should be used if you don't need to keep track of the changes made to the entities - e.g. you're loading entities to display in a grid.

Recommended reading:

[Entity Framework and AsNoTracking](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/4/2/entity_framework_and_asnotracking)